# chosen.js calls window.onbeforeunload in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery-chosen

I have a small problem with chosen.js library.

I have a mechanism on my page which detects changes being made to any input element of the form. Whenever user redirects from the page, I use window.onbeforeunload to prompt her about unsaved changes in the form.

Everything works fine, apart of IE (am using v10). For some reason, chosen.js fires window.onbeforeunload whenever I click on it to expand or collapse dropdown list.

Have you got any idea how to stop it?

Comment: Not really an answer, but it may well solve the issue. I suggest that you consider Select2. It's built on Chosen, has a much more robust API, and is actively developed. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2

Comment: Thanks very much. Will keep that in mind. In the meantime, found a solution (below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution eventually. Need to add onclick attribute to every chosen dropdown list anchor tag and call window.onbeforeunload = null

In my case, I've put

```
$(".chzn-single").attr("onclick", "window.onbeforeunload = null;");
```

After setting up chosen library